# Finding power series expansion of $\frac{1+2x}{1-x-x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find the power series expansion of $\frac{1+2x}{1-x-x^2}$ but I did not know how to do it, I that I have to use $\frac{1}{1-x}$=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$, I tried to multiply both sites for $\frac{1}{x}$ and I think that I could be $\frac{1}{x-x^2}$=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n-1}$ also I Thought that I can multiply both sites for 1-2x but I am not sure

Comment: You could try noticing the function is $-(ln(g(x)))'$  where $g(x)=1-x-x^2$,  plug the quadratic into the expansion of $\ln(x)$ then term by term differentiate

Answer (score 1):

To partially solve your problem you can do a [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) and end up with an expression of the form

$$k+\frac{a}{b+cx} + \frac{d}{f+gx}$$

Maybe it gets easier from that point?